# Strange behavior accessing a property in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to access a value in my object:

```
<input type="text" name="address-search" 
       placeholder="43 Roxling Drive Boston, MA" 
       class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off">

select: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui);
    $('input[name="address-search"]').val(ui.item.label);
}
```

Here's the result of the `console.log` call:

[image]

Here's the strange bit:

If I `console.log(ui.item.label)` I get: `Boston, Massachusetts, United States`.

If I call `$('input[name="address-search"]').val(ui.item.label);` I only get `Boston`. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe input has maxlength set and value is trimmed when setting value that is too long?

Comment: Check input size attribute.

Comment: Is the label stored as a string? If not then I have a funny feeling the commas are up to no good

Comment: @Tal size attribute has nothing to do with it. maxlength is, though.

Comment: I've edited in the html for the input into the question. There is no max length attribute.

Comment: A demo please, we can't reproduce without more information

Comment: Also try to pass that value to any other input and check the result. Maybe it's the autocomplete widget interfere here.

Comment: " I only get Boston" - when you `console.log($('input[name="address-search"]').val())` or inside the input field?

Comment: It works in this demo I made; http://jsfiddle.net/RLGkN/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From jQuery UI autocomplete doc:

> **select**
>
> Triggered when an item is selected from the menu. The default action
>   is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected
>   item. Canceling this event prevents the value from being updated. [...]

What happens here: you replace the value in the input wrapped by into 'autocomplete' widget - but then the widget replaces it by itself. ) Add `return false;` to your function to make it work.

As a sidenote, you don't have to look up the DOM for that element again:

```
this.value = ui.item.label;
```

... should do the trick. )

Comment: Ugh +1, you beat me to it :)

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you!